# spec for nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

My routes are:

```
resources :posts
  resources :images
end
```

and I want to write spec for ImagesController:

```
it "renders the index template" do
  get :index, {:id => @post.id}
  expect(response).to render_template("index")
end
```

the error is

```
No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"images", :id=>"19"}
```

How do I fix this?

edit:

fixed with the `post_id` but seems it still doesn't get the parameter:

the new error is

```
Failure/Error: get :index, {post_id: @post.id}
     NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
```

index view:

```
  def index
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @calculations = @post.something + 1
  end
```

Comment: `get :index, :post_id => @post.id`

Comment: @AndreyDeineko `Failure/Error: get :index, {:post_id => @post.id}
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass`
and I have the @post definied of course

Comment: DO you think I can help you with the latest one? At least it no longer says No routes, so it solves the issue

Comment: I can add it as an answer, you can accept it and then ask a new one, unless you understand what's wrong on your own

Comment: You can not change your problems on the fly. Initially you were getting `No route match` error, I helped you to solve it. This one **is another** question, because it exposes different problem.

Comment: As I said, since the initial issue is solved, you should ask a new question with your new issue (optionally you can accept the answer if it was helpful).

Comment: @AndreyDeineko yes, and produce 9999 questions about not passing the same parameter. If you'd like to help, you're welcome, but please leave the question alone, I don't feel like spamming people here.

Comment: then provide more info in your question so that you are sure it is solved correctly and fully. How am I supposed to guess, where this `+` is?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko the question is about implementing a working spec, not the error => see the topic.

Comment: @post = Post.find(params[:post_id]) should be `@post = Post.find(params[:id])`

Comment: If you are not about spamming people read about `how to ask` on stackoverflow :) edited the asnwer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be passing the `post_id` parameter:

```
get :index, post_id: @post.id
```

## EDIT

after you updated the question with proper info we can see, that there are some issues with your code:

```
@post = Post.find(params[:post_id]) # should be Post.find(params[:id])
@calculations = @post.something + 1 # thus this is `nil` + 1 - error
```

Comment: actually `params[:post_id]` is fine cause it's even more nested. Thanks for help with the first error, debugged the rest myself!

Comment: @J.Doe didn't know from your question that `resources :posts` are nested as well. But good you've found it